# gnome-maps fails to launch in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome

Recently (within the past few weeks) gnome-maps fails to launch in Ubuntu 20.04. It used to work. My only change has been installing updates from Canonical as they are released.

When launching I get the following warnings (and a few more):

```
(org.gnome.Maps:26721): Gtk-WARNING **: 09:15:00.496: Attempting to add a widget with type GtkImage to a container of type GtkClutterOffscreen, but the widget is already inside a container of type GtkClutterOffscreen, please remove the widget from its existing container first.

(org.gnome.Maps:26721): Gjs-WARNING **: 09:15:00.523: JS ERROR: TypeError: action is null
_setRevealSidebar@resource:///org/gnome/Maps/js/mainWindow.js:537:9
_createSidebar/<@resource:///org/gnome/Maps/js/mainWindow.js:168:61
addPoint@resource:///org/gnome/Maps/js/routeQuery.js:203:14
_init@resource:///org/gnome/Maps/js/sidebar.js:95:21
_createSidebar@resource:///org/gnome/Maps/js/mainWindow.js:166:23
_init@resource:///org/gnome/Maps/js/mainWindow.js:113:30
_createWindow@resource:///org/gnome/Maps/js/application.js:265:28
vfunc_activate@resource:///org/gnome/Maps/js/application.js:284:14
main@resource:///org/gnome/Maps/js/main.js:57:24
run@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/script/package.js:222:19
start@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/script/package.js:206:5
@/usr/bin/gnome-maps:2:17
```

Comment: it is fixed now,just update ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: I just tried it after applying the latest updates, still failing on my 20.04.2 LTS with GNOME 3.36.8

Comment: it is fixed for me,running ubuntu 20.04.3 and maps v 3.36.1-1ubuntu1

Comment: tested on two of my pc`s both with GNOME 3.36.8

Comment: @trondhansen ok I finally got it, after a reboot, installing an update to gnome-maps, and another reboot -- now it works again.  Yay!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem as have others. Gnome-maps used to work fine in Ubuntu 20.04 but since one system update a few weeks ago, it refuses to open.

The problem is already resolved upstream (3.36.7) but 20.04 LTS is running 3.36.1 and noone seems to be willing to update it. I would be glad to do it myself alas I can't do it.

(See here: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-maps/-/issues/382)

Comment: OK thanks for letting me know.  I'm not sure how to pull Canonical's chain on this.  Hopefully an LTS developer is paying attention.

Answer (score 0):

It's been solved in Linux Mint in the meantime. They've backported GNOME Maps 3.38.2-1 in Linux Mint 20.2., 20.1 and 20.

I so hope that someone is going to implement it in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS soon as well.

See here (post #7 by Clement Lefebvre):

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-maps/+bug/1930699